# Unknown entity bean class, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I am building an application for a research project at my University, developed in Java using Eclipse and eclipselink JPA for persistance. The application is composed of 3 Eclipse projects, call them for simplicity A, B and C. Projects A and C use JPA to access their databases, DB_A and DB_C. Project A uses the built-in Java derby database, and project C uses MySQL database.
Both projects A and C define some entities and an entity manager. The operations work fine when tested in each project. Then, project C was added as reference to project B, and project B to project A. (A->B->C)
Project A (main application) uses a local database DB_A and needs to access functionality of project B, that calls project C that connects to the second database DB_C. This is when the following exception occurs, thrown from project C (that worked fine before):

**Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown
entity bean class: class database.model.VMModelSim, please verify that this
class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.**

```
   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:707)

   at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:588)

   at database.dao.DAO.find(DAO.java:40)

   at database.facade.FacadeImpl.find(FacadeImpl.java:32)

   at simulationmanager.services.VMServiceImpl.getById(VMServiceImpl.java:89)

   at simulationmanager.services.VMServiceImpl.getById(VMServiceImpl.java:1)

   at monitoring.util.ResourceAdapter.updateResource(ResourceAdapter.java:29)

   at monitoring.QueueProcessor.writeMessageToDB(QueueProcessor.java:58)

   at monitoring.QueueProcessor.run(QueueProcessor.java:44)
```

Each project A and C have their own persistance.xml file, the difference being the persistence-unit name, the classes declared and the database driver.

This is the persistance xml file of project A.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>database.model.Server</class>
    <class>database.model.VirtualMachine</class>
    <class>database.model.CPU</class>
    <class>database.model.CPUCore</class>
    <class>database.model.HDD</class>
    <class>database.model.RAM</class>
    <class>database.model.DataCenter</class>
    <class>database.model.Rack</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
        value="jdbc:derby:/var/lib/one/workspace/databases/cloudDatabase;create=true" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test" />

      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
      < <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />  >
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
        value="database" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What can I do to fix this? The entity is marked with @Entity. The operations work fine if only one database is accessed. I think that the problem appears because of the two databases that must be simultaneously accessed. Can we modify somehow the persistance.xml file?

Comment: How have you defined the persistence units, and are there any other warnings when starting up?  The persistence units should have unique names so that A's persistence unit can be found separate from C's.

Answer (score 2):

We managed to figure out the problem. In both projects A and C we had the same database access classes in the same package names: DBConnect.java in package database.connection. Here we defined the persistence manager name (that was different!).
When the projects were run separately, each project accessed its own connection class. However, when only project A was run and it referenced B and then C, the class from project C that created the connection to its database created an object with the class defined in project A (because of the identical name). Consequently, it was trying to create a persistence manager for the model defined in project A, and write objects defined in project C. I believe that this was the error source.